# perl to generate string to match regex

Tags: regex, string, perl, random, perl-module

I try to find a way to generate string that matches regex, for example, the following regex:

```
[A-Z]{6,6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9]{3,3}){0,1}
```

There are some perl modules on Cpan which I tried that doesn't work:
-> String::Random
-> Regexp::Genex

The String::Random shows () is not supported.
Regex::Genex reports error on strings($regex) with this one.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show what you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of quantifiers such as `{6,6}` and `{3,3}`? `{0,1}` can be written as `?`.

Comment: Read the chapter Regex String Generation in [Higher Order Perl](https://hop.perl.plover.com/book/).

Comment: Tip: `a{6,6}` can be written `a{6}`

Comment: Tip: `a{0,1}` can be written `?`

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, I just want only 1 combination, not all.

Comment: About how to write these regex, it may look dull, but that's another topic. :)

Comment: I think the [infinite monkey theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem) could work here... ;)

Comment: @simbabque, I'm so posting a solution that uses that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a general solution and you aren't will to work towards fixing String::Random, you could use a [large number of monkeys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem).

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my $pattern = qr/^[A-Z]{6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9]{3})?\z/;

my $min_len =  0;
my $max_len = 15;
my @syms = map chr, 0x20..0x7E;

my $s;
while (1) {
   $s = join '', map { $syms[rand(@syms)] } 1..$min_len+rand($max_len-$min_len+1);
   last if $s =~ $pattern;
}

say $s;
```

This solution literally generates "completely" random strings until it find one that matches. *It's an awful approach*, and it can be quite slow.

You can speed it up the solution by restricting the random string generator (via `$min_len`, `$max_len` and `@syms`). That said, the more you restrict these, the fewer patterns this solution will support. For example, using `$min_len = 8; $max_len = 11; @syms = ( 'A'..'Z', '0'..'9' );` will be insanely faster for the example pattern, but using those parameters might prevent it from working for other patterns.

Also note that this approach skews the odds. Some matching strings are more likely to be generated than others. For example, the monkeys are incredibly more likely to produce `A` than `AAA` given `^[A-Z]{1,3}\z`.

Comment: Maybe run with Parallel::ForkManager if you need more monkeys.

Comment: This works, except that the speed is a bit lousy (~5sec or even longer per string generation), but at least it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course it's slow. Added some info to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[String::Random](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Random) is exactly what you want. The only catch is that it doesn't support `(...)` (or `(?:...)`).

Either work to get support for that added to String::Random for a general purpose solution, or write up a specific-purpose solution as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my $s = '';

for (1..6) {
   $s .= ('A'..'Z')[rand(26)];
}

$s .= ('A'..'Z', '2'..'9')[rand(34)];

$s .= ('A'..'N', 'P'..'Z', '0'..'9')[rand(35)];

for (1..rand(2)) {
   for (1..3) {
      $s .= ('A'..'Z', '0'..'9')[rand(36)];
   }
}

say $s;
```

Comment: Is there a reason you put the search.cpan.org link instead of metacpan?

Comment: Never used the latter.

Comment: Oh, I never realized in your answers.