# Parse strings of certain patterns: Extract multiple phrases from one phrase

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

So from one of the phrases of this pattern: `You can't make omelet(te)s(or an omelet(te)) without breaking eggs`, I need to extract four phrases:
`You can't make omelets without breaking eggs`
`You can't make omelettes without breaking eggs`
`You can't make an omelet without breaking eggs`
`You can't make an omelette without breaking eggs`

Is this possible using just `Regex` or if not, how to implement this in the programming languages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regex is sort of what you would want to use going in the opposite direction.  That is, the pattern `You can't make (?:omlets|omlettes|an omlet|an omelette) without breaking eggs` is what you would use to match any of the four variants.

Comment: Yeah, I guess to extract is harder than to match. :)

Comment: There is a Java library called [Xeger](https://code.google.com/archive/p/xeger/) that does this kind of thing.

Comment: Xegger looks interesting. I'll look into this. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that page; further, the solution for that question doesn't even work here as there is no regex to test against here.

Comment: As you write code to break the string by `(or`  you'll find the possibility of nested parens inside the `(or...)` to be a problem: how to find the closing paren? That's where a module like [Text::Balanced](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text/Balanced.html) can help, but there's still going to be some good work to do.  If nested parens were disallowed (so, no `(or ... ab(c(d)))` but only one level of parens inside `(or...)` can happen), which is  a reasonable possibility, then you can parse the `(or...` away to find the closing paren.  This is still a nice little parser that you need to write.

Comment: This had been closed as a duplicate of an interesting page [perl to generate string to match regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46796737/4653379).  I voted to "reopen," since I don't think it's a dupe as I stated in a comment above, but I didn't realize that my vote alone would do it; if anybody has a problem with mine reopening please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Edited with updated code. Original message after <=====> line.

Here is an updated code for multiple or, but again using the parenthesis and pipe method.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $string = "You can't make (omelet(te)s)|(an omelet(te))|(the omlet(te))|(scrambbled egg(s)) without breaking eggs";
my @count = $string=~m/\|/g;
my $x = scalar @count;
my $a= '\\|(\\(.+\\))';
my $search='(\\(.+\\))';
## Build your search string
for (my $i=1;$i<=$x;$i++) {
  $search.=$a;
}
$search.=$end;
my @c = $string=~m/$search/gm;

##  Create another string to destroy and reconstruct later. ($stripped)
my $stripped = $string;
$stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$3/;
foreach(@c) {

#remove parenthesis
  $_=~s/^\((.+)\)$/$1/;
  $pattern1 = $_;
## Recontruct $stripped to original
  $stripped = $string;
##  Strip enclosed item out of string
  $_=~s/\(.+\)//;
##  Insert manipulated string into $stripped
  $stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$_$3/;
  print "$stripped\n";
##  Pattern 1 Strip enclosed item out of string
  $pattern1=~s/\((.+)\)/$1/;
## Recontruct $stripped to original
  $stripped = $string;
##  Insert manipulated string into $stripped
  $stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$pattern1$3/;
  print "$stripped\n";

}
```

That should cover multiple options.

Original message below:
<======>

Maybe if you reconstruct the phrase a bit, it would be easier.  Like putting the options within a parenthesis and separators, then it would be easier. If the option of syntaxing the phrase is not an option, then ignore my suggestion :-)

Sample phrase:
You can't make (omelet(te)s)|(an omelet(te)) without breaking eggs

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string = "You can't make (omelet(te)s)|(an omelet(te)) without breaking eggs";
my @c = $string=~m/(\(.+\))\|(\(.+\))/gm;

##  Create another string to destroy and reconstruct later. ($stripped)
my $stripped = $string;
$stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$3/;

foreach(@c) {
#remove parenthesis
  $_=~s/^\((.+)\)$/$1/;
  $pattern1 = $_;
## Recontruct $stripped to original
  $stripped = $string;
##  Strip enclosed item out of string
  $_=~s/\(.+\)//;
##  Insert manipulated string into $stripped
  $stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$_$3/;
  print "$stripped\n";
##  Pattern 1 Strip enclosed item out of string
  $pattern1=~s/\((.+)\)/$1/;
##  Recontruct $stripped to original
  $stripped = $string;
##  Insert manipulated string into $stripped
  $stripped=~s/^(.*?)(\(.+\)\|\(.+\))((.*?$)|($))/$1$pattern1$3/;
print "$stripped\n";

}
```

If you want to go deeper, you can add multiple enclosed parenthesis within the outside parenthesis to replace and loop it like with did on the initial string @c.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. @hashtagjet One thing though, `You can't make omelet(te)s(or an omelet(te)) without breaking eggs` is one of many examples of similar pattern. i.e. there could be multiple `(or…)` in one phrase.

Comment: I will make an edit for multiple or but using that ()|() method.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe yes, it would be possible with an expression similar to:

```
You can't make (?:an)?\s*\b(?:omelett?e?s?)\b\swithout breaking eggs
```

---

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LkAUfx/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/LkAUfx/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

#### Test

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'You can\'t make omelets without breaking eggs';
my $regex = qr/^You can't make (?:an)?\s*\b(?:omelett?e?s?)\b\swithout breaking eggs$/p;

if ( $str =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print "${^MATCH}";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and regex alone can't extract the various combinations which your pattern is using.  Please re-read the question.